# javax systemcompiler don't generate class files

Tags: java, jar, javac, java-compiler-api

This is my code to compile some java sourcefiles:

```
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    dependencies = getJarFiles(this.libPath);
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

    ArrayList<File> sourceFiles = getSourceFiles(this.apiGeneratedSrcPath);
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(sourceFiles);
    try {
        fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File(this.genClassDir)));
        fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, dependencies);
        if(!compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits1 ).call())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error on compiling API");
        fileManager.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and i also tried this version:

```
    optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-Xmaxerrs", "20"));
    optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-d", "target\\classes"));
    optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-cp", classpath));


    //Java files
    System.out.println("Get source files");
    ArrayList<File> sourcefiles =  getSourceFiles(this.apiGeneratedSrcPath);
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(sourcefiles);
    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, optionList, null, compilationUnits1 );

    System.out.println("Compile API");
    boolean compiled = task.call();
    if(!compiled)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error on compiling API");
    System.out.println("Compile API Done");
```

But in my genClassDir (which should be output for my class files) there are no class files generated, still i dont get a compiler error.

I am also getting htis warning which i cannot resolve but it should break the build process:

```
Access restriction: The method 'StandardJavaFileManager.setLocation(JavaFileManager.Location, Iterable<? extends File>)' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\rt.jar')
```

Any ideas why the compiler dont geenerate .class files from my .java sources??

Comment: I tried your first version and it works fine.. it creates classes.. I tried it with a very simple class with no code..

Comment: Ok i checked all source files for being present but still there are no class files generated... i am really clueless whats happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should not have written this as answer but in comments I cannot format the code properly. Here is what I did and it worked

```
package hello;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.StandardLocation;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        List<File> sourceFiles = Arrays.asList(new File("C://project//src//hello//Hello.java"));
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(sourceFiles);
        try {
            fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("C://project//classes//")));
            if(!compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits1 ).call())
                throw new IllegalStateException("Error on compiling API");
            fileManager.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And Hello.java

```
package hello;

public class Hello {

}
```

And the output was a class file :  C://project//classes//hello//Hello.class

Comment: do you get this warning which i have in my Question on the bottom? Also which jdk are you using?

Comment: Hi, i swapped to Java 8 and now its working again... strange that it didnt work with jdk 1.7_0_80